# How to cover code 100%

Tags: apex

```
public  class MyPositionClass {

    public List<Position__c> pos;
    public  void  updatePositionRecords() {
        pos = [select id, Name, Apex__c, Close_Date__c, Days_Open__c, Educational_Requirements__c,
               Functional_Area__c, Hire_By__c, Job_Description__c, Job_Level__c, Location__c, Max_Pay__c, Min_Pay__c,
               Open_Date__c, Responsibilities__c, Travel_Required__c , Skills_Required__c   from Position__c  where RecordTypeid = '0126F0000016zuu'];
        for (Position__c p : pos) {
            if (p.Name == 'Salesforce Busyness Anylyst') {
                p.Close_Date__c = Date.Today().addDays(30);
                p.Hire_By__c = Date.Today().addDays(90);
                if (p.Travel_Required__c == false) {
                    p.Travel_Required__c = true;
                }
                if (p.Java__c == false) {
                    p.Java__c = true;
                }
            }
            update pos;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? also post your test class code. Also don't hard code Ids!

Comment: If you are not sure how to write a unit test, you should head over to **[Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_testing)**. At SFSE, we expect you to make a good faith effort before asking for help here. If you have already written a test class, please **[edit]** your above post to include it, and also indicate which lines you are struggling to cover.

Comment: I suggest you fix this code before putting in production. 100% coverage is not as important as code that won't crash on your users.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the test class which will give you code coverage about 80%. It will depend on data in position object.if you want it to be 100% create the all possible testing case and then run the method.

```
  @isTest
    public class TestMyPositionClass  
    {
        static testmethod void TestMyPositionClass()
        {
           MyPositionClass mpPosition = new MyPositionClass();
           mpPosition.updatePositionRecords();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually, this would be closer to 20% coverage or so. The bulk of the logic needs at least one record to perform.

Comment: Yes, it will depend on data.